# Simple RESTful Java client in Google App Engine using java.net.URL

Tags: java, google-app-engine, rest

I'm creating web app in **Google App Engine** which uses external **RESTful** services.
After a little research I've opted for using just the **java.net.URL** class, instead of any JAX-RS API such as **Jersey**, because these APIs have some compatibility problems with GAE, or they are only compatible with some versions and so on... and I don't like this issues very much.

Following [**this tutorial**](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/), to call the REST services I do:

```
URL url = new URL("rest-service-url");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
//process the response...
```

Then I process the JSON response using [**Google's GSON**](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/), which is also fully compatible with GAE.

First of all, in your opinion this is a good option?

And then, I'd like to centralize this code in some way, because I have many different calls to services in my app, so how could I do that? I thought of creating some class with a method like this:

```
public BufferedReader sendRESTRequest (URL url)
    //previous code here...        
}
```

But I'm not sure about... this method should be static? synchronized? Should I create an HttpURLConnection object inside the method or in the class? etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look [here](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) if you are allowed to use Apache libs for your project. Why reinvent the wheel

Something on the lines of

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
private String poolTimeOutMillSecStr = System.getProperty("CONN_TIME_OUT_MILLSEC", "60000");

    private String maxTotalConnStr = System.getProperty("MAX_TOTAL_CONN", "400");

    private String maxConnPerRouteStr = System.getProperty("MAX_CONN_PER_ROUTE", "200");

    HttpUtility httpUtilty;

    private String baseUrl = System.getProperty("BASE_URL", "http://localhost:8888");

    private String userName;

    private String password;

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        int poolTimeOutMillSec = Integer.parseInt(poolTimeOutMillSecStr);
        int maxTotalConn = Integer.parseInt(maxTotalConnStr);
        int maxConnPerRoute = Integer.parseInt(maxConnPerRouteStr);
        httpUtilty = new HttpUtility(poolTimeOutMillSec, maxTotalConn, maxConnPerRoute);
        httpUtilty.initialize(baseUrl);
        userName = "admin";
        password = "admin";

    }
}
```

And using it like

```
HttpResponse response = httpUtilty.postRequest(path, null, ins, null);
HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not trying to reinvent anything... I'm just following [Google's tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/urlfetch/usingjavanet).

Comment: I have the same question as such. I need to call a REST service with user authentication from my Servlet in my Google App Engine application. Any help?